# Solve the following differential equation: $xy''-y'+k^2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, bessel-functions

It is not an Euler equation. I tried power series, but I can't develop them around $x=0$. I also tried dividing Bessel's equation by $x$, but it doesn't seem to be possible to arrive at my equation. 
Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are a few pages of algebra behind the Bessel function series solution by the way. It's not terrible but requires some tricks and cleverness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the analytic solution of this ODE involves Bessel functions of first and second kind, a power series approach is the only way out. Let's transform our initial expression :

$$xy'' - y' + c^2y = 0 \Rightarrow y'' - \frac{y'}{x}+\frac{c^2}{x}y=0$$

Since for $x=0$ we have an undeterminate form, we recall the [Frobenius Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), which is **exactly** suited for such cases. For this particular example, $q(x) = k^2$.

We now seek a power series solution of the form 
$$y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A_kz^{k+r}, \quad A_0 \neq 0$$
By differentiating, we yield :
$$y'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+r)A_kz^{(k+r)-1} \quad \text{and} \quad y''(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty [(k+r)-1](k+r)A_kz^{(k+r)-2}$$

By substituting now in the ODE, you should be able to yield a reccurence relation involving $\{A_k\}$.

Comment: says: "As the analytic solution of this ODE involves Bessel functions of first and second kind, a power series approach is the only way out" 

So am I given to understand that the solution to my diff eq can be written analytically in terms of first and second kind Bessel functions? Why use power series then?

Comment: @asd11 By experience one can see in what cases you use Power Series. Now, for the Bessel Function part, you cannot reach the solution expression by hand. The Bessel Functions describe exactly what you do analytically, by power series. Note that they are not ordinary functions. [More context here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

Comment: Just for the sake of your curiosity, the solution is written as : $$y(x) = c_1k^2xJ_2(2k\sqrt{x}) + c_2k^2xY_2(2k\sqrt{x})$$ Now if you take a look at the link, you'll understand the complexity of this and thus the need of a way out involving hand-solved problems, aka the power series weapon !

Comment: Ok. You gave me enough food for thought. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @asd11 Always happy to help!

Comment: I followed the steps indicated in the wikipedia article. So one of the independent solutions is $y_1(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2A_0\dfrac{\alpha^{2k}}{k!(k+2)!}x^{k+2}$.

Comment: Supposing my calculation is correct. @Rebellos, how did you deduce the fact that that is a bessel function of first/second kind?

Comment: I changed the constant $k$ in my equation by $\alpha$

Comment: @asd11 Hi, the decomposition mentioned is exactly what Bessel functions achieve. Of course, such an observation cannot be logically made, the result mentioned is the solution yielded by Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

If I have not made substitution errors we should get by substituting (I'm not writing the details, just the odes I arrived to on paper)

$y(x)=u\left(2k\sqrt{x}\right)\iff u(x)=y\left(\left(\dfrac{x}{2k}\right)^2\right)$

the new ode written below : $$x(u''+u)=(2k^2+1)u'$$

Now set $n=k^2+1$ and $u(x)=x^n\,v(x)$

You get this ode : $$x^2v''+xv'+(x^2-n^2)v=0$$

Which is the Bessel differential equation: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Whose solution is $v(x)=c_1J_n(x)+c_2H_n(x)$

Explaining the result you get in the other answer comments by Rebellos.